# Why is DateDiff producing different results to DateInterval

Tags: php

I am probably missing something obvious, but why is the output of the below hugely different??

```
function dateDiff($start,$end = null,$format = 'Y-m-d'){

    $start = '2021-12-01 12:00:00';
    $end = '2022-05-11 12:00:00';

    echo $start.'--'.$end.'<br>';

    $origin = new DateTime($start);
    $target = new DateTime($end ?? $start);

    $interval = $origin->diff($target)->d;

    $out = array(
        'diff'  => $interval,
        'dates' => array(),
    );

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period = new DatePeriod($origin,$interval,$target);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        $out['dates'][] = $dt->format($format);
    }

    $out['dates'][] = $end;

    print'<pre>';print_r($out);print'</pre>';
    exit;

return $out;
}
```

I would expect the `diff` figure to be the same as the number of values in the `dates` array. As it is, for some reason the `diff()` function is returning 10 days??

Answer (score 1):

After outputting the $diff object using `print_r($interval)` it appers there is a "days" property (as opposed to the "d") which gives the *full days* as opposed to a rubbish top level difference.

`$origin->diff($target)->days;`